# Calling Web Service error "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Connection refused."

Tags: web-services

Dears,
I have the following web service from client to call:
http://ajec.proxym-it.net/Ajec_sso_api/authenticate.wsdl

When I try to consume it, I got the this error :
    The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Connection refused.

The inner exception is: {"The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway."}

Here is my code:

```
AuthenticateService.AuthenticatePortClient oAuthenticatePortClient = new AuthenticateService.AuthenticatePortClient();
AuthenticateService.authenticateRequest oauthenticateRequest = new AuthenticateService.authenticateRequest();

oauthenticateRequest.serviceId = "MobileTeam";
oauthenticateRequest.serviceKey = "AJEC1";
oauthenticateRequest.userName = "MMelhem";
oauthenticateRequest.password = "P@$$w0rd";

AuthenticateService.authenticateResponse oregisterUserResponse = oAuthenticatePortClient.authenticate(oauthenticateRequest);
```

and the web.config is:

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
<proxy usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="False" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="AuthenticatePortSoap11" />
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="http://172.16.0.82:80/Ajec_sso_api/authenticate"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthenticatePortSoap11"
contract="AuthenticateService.AuthenticatePort"    name="AuthenticatePortSoap11" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Has this service ever worked for anybody? Is this the first time it is being consumed on as webservice? Is it working for others right now? HTTP 502 means bad gateway (the backend server is giving problems). Next step would be to check (with whoever is managing the webservice) the status of the backend (Other than things like if the userid/password are correct).

Comment: When try to test it on SoupUI Application it work but when try to consume it on code it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replace the endpoint address from
    http://172.16.0.82:80/Ajec_sso_api/authenticate
to 
    http://ajec.proxym-it.net/Ajec_sso_api/authenticate

Answer (score 0):

What tool did you use to generate your client code (or hand-coded it)?

I used wsimport and I got slightly different code than yours. Since the IP seems to be in local domain (172.16.0.82), I couldn't test it. If you are interested, you could try it.

I used wsimport to generate/compile client class files:

```
wsimport -keep http://ajec.proxym-it.net/Ajec_sso_api/authenticate.wsdl
```

Then coded the client like this:

```
import com.ajec_sso.authenticate.*;    
public class TClient {
    static AuthenticatePortService service = new AuthenticatePortService();
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
       try {
            AuthenticatePort port = service.getAuthenticatePortSoap11();    
            AuthenticateRequest req = new AuthenticateRequest();
            AuthenticateResponse res = new AuthenticateResponse();    
            req.setServiceId("MobileTeam");
            req.setServiceKey("AJEC1");
            req.setUserName("MMelhem");
            req.setPassword("P@$$w0rd");    
            res = port.authenticate(req);
       } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Compiled like this (the generated com directory is in current directory).

```
javac TClient.java
```